# java 8 certandkeygen exception during runtime

Tags: java, java-8, java-security

I have a third party java package which is compiled using Java 6 version and this package is deployed in java 8 environment. Now I am seeing the follow exception during runtime.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-2" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/security/x509/CertAndKeyGen
       at com.xxx.ws.security.impl.DefaultSecurityStore.generateSelfSignedEntry(Unknown Source)
       at com.xxx.ws.security.impl.SecurityPluginUtil.sign(Unknown Source)
       at com.xxx.ws.security.impl.ProcessingContext.processOutbound(Unknown Source)
       at com.xxx.ws.security.impl.BaseSecurityEnvironment.secureOutboundMessage(Unknown Source)
       at com.xxx.em.launch.message.LaunchRequestMessage.sendTo(Unknown Source)
```

I did research for this exception and I discovered that Java 8 moved the `CertAndKeyGen` class to `sun.security.tools.keytool` package. 
But in this case, this package is compiled using java 6 and referring to `sun.security.x509.CertAndKeyGen` package. 
What could be the alternative approach to mitigate this issue.
. Thanks for your time.